# oop design for handling objects polymorphically

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have objects of different types derived from one base (for example circle, rectangle, polygon... and so on) and I have set of predefined operations that can be applied to those objects (for example move, rotate, copy...and so on).
The solution I like in this situation is visitor pattern. I have visitors for every operation which contains full set of operations for all types. This allows me to add new functions to the objects without changing the object itself. Operations are definitely going to be changed and added more frequently then new object types, so that's really great, but there is one problem.
All stated above is implemented as a library which may be (and will be) extended by another programmers in a future. Programmers may add new type of objects and either implement operations or not. For example one may add "triangle" class that supports move, but doesn't support rotation. In this case programmer wouldn't be able to extend my visitor to handle move operation for his object.
I see one more solution - having interfaces like i_movable, i_rotatable, i_copyable. Every class implements one or more of this interfaces, then I check in my library, if specified object supports given interface with dynamic_cast and apply the operation. Something like

```
if (i_movable* m = dynamic_cast<i_movable>(obj)) m->move(10, 20);
```

but I don't like this solution much. Can anyone suggest something better?

That's may not be really important for OOP design, but the language of implementation is C++, so I'm limited with C++ capabilities.

**update**

If no one can think of a better solution could you please at least leave a vote for proposed one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you described here with interfaces is pretty much how COM works. Can you describe the "I don't like this" part? In which part are you limitied by C++? As far as I can see, you answered your own question.

Comment: Yes, it's something similar to COM. I don't like that I have to put all functions in one class. For example I have to implement copy serialization, move, rotation and all other operations for triangle in the triangle class itself. This makes the class very big and hard to support (there is really lot of different operations). I also try to avoid casts wherever it's possible. I don't say that I wouldn't go with that solution, I'm just wondering if there is something better.

Comment: Concerning C++ limitations: I don't mean that I have some sort of good solution, but I'm limited by C++. Just mentioned to do not confuse other people and not make them suggest solutions that cannot be implemented using C++.

Comment: I agree with you, but can you write some generic code for serialization, moving, rotating and other required operations?

Comment: Well, I can write generic code for some of the operations, but not for the others. For example I can write `move` function that will work for set of geometries, but I can't write generic serialization function for copying and saving the object.

Comment: I guess you are reffering to the amount of code inside the class when you say "This makes the class very big", because methods are not making the class bigger (in terms of sizeof). Anyway, although many people don't like casting, it's the part of C/C++ language. Maybe it's not "the pure OO design" described by the book, but the bottom line is - it will do the job. IMHO, the OO is here to serve us, not the other way around.

Comment: natko: Sure, I mean the interface of the class (not the size in terms of number of bytes). Class that implements 20 interfaces and 50 methods doesn't look like properly designed one :) Concerning cast - I agree with you, sometimes it's necessary, so I don't say it's bad to use cast and that's why `query interface` solution is bad, I just say there might be a better one, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
if (i_movable* m = dynamic_cast<i_movable>(obj)) m->move(10, 20);
```

you can use some template meta programming tricks (take a look into [boost::is_base_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html)) :

```
#include "boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp" 
#include <iostream>

struct i_move
{
    virtual void move(const float, const float ) = 0;
};
struct Triangle
{
    // not movable
};
struct Circle : i_move
{
    virtual void move(const float, const float )
    {
        // move me
    }
};

template< class D >
bool IsMovable( D&)
{
    return boost::is_base_of<i_move,D>::value;
}

int main()
{
    Circle a;
    Triangle b;
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<IsMovable(a)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<IsMovable(b)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function-template `IsMovable` only have one type-parameter? The type of the base-class that expresses movability should always be the same, right?

Comment: All those objects derive from one base (let's say geometry) and you deal with base class pointers, so I can't implement it this way, we need dynamic cast here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, if the operation is not supported, you do nothing (or more generally, have uniform behaviour independent of the object in question). Then a simple solution is to provide the default behaviour in the base class, and then if a derived class doesn't implement its own version, the default behaviour automatically kicks in without any extra machinery.

If I recall correctly, in Borland's Turbo Vision such methods were called "pseudo abstract": They are not really abstract (it is not disallowed to call them, and there's no strict need to override them in derived classes), but they do nothing unless overridden.

Comment: Yes. You got it correctly, but as I already said there is about 50 different operations and I don't want to put them all in a base class. I don't want too much functions in one class.